# Help identify chandelier/needs a new glass globe

Tags: replacement, glass, lamp

I recently broke one of the glass globes, and can't find a maker label anywhere. If it's hard to know the maker, is there a place to buy single domes?
[image]

Comment: lighting store should have something similar ... you may have to buy five to get a match

Comment: If you find an answer or comment helpful please accept it that’s how we say thanks, it also helps others that have a similar question find an answer that has been accepted when the search function is used.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you've got a few choices. You can look for another globe in your home store. They have lighting sections and sell replacements for some standard globes. You'll have better luck if you go to  commercial lighting store and look for/order a replacement. You can purchase 5 globes similar to the ones you have and replace all five. if you do this, buy an extra one just in case. These lighting fixtures are so mass produced I doubt they even can be identified.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll check out commercial lighting stores. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Specialty lighting stores (every big city has a few) will have a wide selection og glass globes available. If they don't have it in stock they can probably get it:

[image]